# How to Make Autodesk Viewer Orthographic by Default

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I am trying to make the autodesk viewer display files in orthographic mode by default. So far the best solution i've come up with is the following:

```
forgeViewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
    function setOrtho() {
      forgeViewer.autocam.homeVector.isPerspective = false;
      forgeViewer.autocam.homeVector.isOrtho = true;
      forgeViewer.autocam.originalHomeVector.isPerspective = false;
      forgeViewer.autocam.originalHomeVector.isOrtho = true;
      forgeViewer.autocam.toOrthographic();
    },
  );
```

This sets home to orthographic and sets the current view to orthographic which is exactly what i'm looking for. The only issue i have is that waiting on the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` means that larger models will load in perspective and then snap to orthographic when all of the geometry is loaded, which can be jarring for users.

**Is there a way to get the viewer to initialize in orthographic sooner so that it doesn't do this?** I've tried waiting on a few other events as well as running `setOrtho` immediately with no event listener and usually it fails to get picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set orthographic view as early (and might work even earlier) as `Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT`:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT, ()=>{
   //...
}
```

See live demo [here](https://output.jsbin.com/suyiyog) - LGTM.

You can also try `viewer.debugEvents(true)` (and here's the [doc](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.html#events) to explain them) to print all the events to console and see which one gets called earlier to suit your needs.